# Invoking grunt concat two times with different options

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I have different options to concat JS files and CSS files.

How can I configure grunt to run such a configuration ?

This doesn't work :

```
concat: {
    js: { // Custom options for JS
        options: {
            separator: '\n',
            sourceMap: true,
            banner: '...',
        },
        core: {
            src: ['src/core/*.js', 'src/core/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'assets/xxxx.js'
        }
    },
    css: { // Default options for CSS
        core: {
            src: ['src/core/*.css', 'src/core/**/*.css'],
            dest: 'assets/xxxx.css'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...so using targets with concat works for me via the `grunt concat:js` and `grunt concat:css` calls.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: There's no error message, but it doesn't concat anything.

Comment: what comes out of using the `--verbose` flag?  that's usually pointed me to the problem.  I only ask because this approach should work *but* the Gruntfile is touchy and often makes me crazy.  I wind up using `--verbose` more often than I'd expect when building new projects.  :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ugly, but it works :

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

grunt.renameTask('concat', 'concatCss');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
// The task is then loaded two times, under 'concat' and 'concatCss' names.

...
concat: {  
    options: {
        separator: '\n',
        sourceMap: true,
        banner: '...',
    },
    core: {
        src: ['src/core/*.js', 'src/core/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'assets/xxxx.js'
    },
concatCss: { // Default options for CSS
    core: {
        src: ['src/core/*.css', 'src/core/**/*.css'],
        dest: 'assets/xxxx.css'
    }
}
```